# UICollectionView doesn't present properly after custom unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a `UICollectionViewController` and a `UIViewController`, I have a custom segue presenting the `UIViewController` from the `UICollectionViewController` and another segue dismissing it however when the dismiss function takes place the `UICollectionViewController` becomes blank and doesn't show the `UIViewControllerCell`s.

The `UICollectionViewController` is also part of a `UITabBarController`.

Here is my code for the two segues, please tell me where I am going wrong:

*The XX, YY, X and Y variables are just coordinates, assume they are all equal to 0.

```
import UIKit

var XX = 0
var YY = 0

class Segue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

    var X = Int()
    var Y = Int()

    override func perform() {
        XX = X
        YY = Y
        openApp()
    }

    func openApp () {

        let sourceViewController = self.source
        let destinationViewController = self.destination


        sourceViewController.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        print("X: \(X),Y: \(Y)")
        destinationViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(X), y: CGFloat(Y), width: screenWidth/1000, height: screenHeight/1000)
        destinationViewController.view.alpha = 0

        sourceViewController.view.addSubview(destinationViewController.view)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            destinationViewController.view.alpha = 1
            destinationViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.screenWidth, height: self.screenHeight)
        }, completion: { success in
            sourceViewController.present(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }

}


class UnwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

    override func perform() {
        closeApp()
    }

    func closeApp () {

        let sourceViewController = self.source
        let destinationViewController = self.destination

        sourceViewController.view.superview?.insertSubview(destinationViewController.view, at: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            sourceViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: XX, y: YY, width: Int(self.screenWidth/1000), height: Int(self.screenHeight/1000))
        }, completion: { success in
            sourceViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line's the crash at? and the message?

Comment: It doesn't crash, when it takes place all of the print functions in the collection view are printed however the actual view is not presented and the screen is just blank (with the tabor at the bottom)

Comment: Can you update the title?

Comment: I don't think I can

Comment: Long shot, But should you be animating away destinationController's frame instead of source in `closeApp()`?

Comment: The source is the UIViewController though, and I'm confident it is because 1. It animates how I want it to and 2. If I print the destinationViewController variable it shows the correct information.              I also just tried animating the destinationViewController and that doesn't work.